# How can I align text across Bootstrap 5 columns?

Tags: css, alignment

I have bootstrap columns set up with photos and a brief description underneath. Because the photos are different heights the text isn't aligned across the columns and it looks pretty bad. I'm sure this is a simple fix but I just can't seem to find it! Thanks in advance

```
<div class="row colabs">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
          <h2>Megan Reitz</h2>
          <img class="collab-pics" src="C:\Users\donal\OneDrive\Desktop\John Higgins Website\Images\megan-reitz.jpg" alt="">
          <p class="collab-texts">Long standing research partner into 'speaking truth to power' and 'workplace activism'</p>
          <a class="collab-links" href="http://www.meganreitz.com/">http://www.meganreitz.com/</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
          <h2>Mark Cole</h2>
          <img class="collab-pics" src="C:\Users\donal\OneDrive\Desktop\John Higgins Website\Images\Mark-Cole.jpg" alt="">
          <p class="collab-texts">Fellow explorer into the intellectual headwaters of current organizational and management practice</p>
          <a class="collab-links" href="https://radicalod.org/">https://radicalod.org/</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxEMc.png)

Answer (score 0):

In this you can go for any one below described solution

1. try to use bootstrap-5 inbuilt classes like "img-fluid"..etc
   reference link :- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/images/
2. either you can set your images to one div as background and use properties like background-position, background-size .. etc
3. you can set apply common height/width for all image elements with this you can control images & after that texts of it..

Comment: Thank you for your answer Divyesh, changing all the photos to the same height needed some tweaking so they didn't look stretched or squashed but I got there eventually! It looks much better now